# Proving that there is a functor $F: Grp \rightarrow Ab$ s.t $F(G)=G_{ab}$- How to deal with the quotient?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups, functors

Let $G$ be a group.  $f$ a group hom. $f:G\rightarrow H     $

I define:
$F(G)=G_{ab}$
and
$F$ : $G$ $\rightarrow$ $G_{ab}$ a homomorphism, where $G_{ab} : = G/[G,G]$ is the abelianization of group $G$.  such that

$F(f):=f_{ab}$ where $f_{ab}([r])=[f(r)]$

I assume F is well-defined on objects, because the abelianization is an ableian group

I think the checks that I have to perform are a part from F mapping identity to the identity and the composition, are :

1. that $f_{ab}$ is a group hom: (provided 2) has been shown as observed in the comments)

$f_{ab}([r][s])=f_{ab}([rs])=[f(rs)]=[f(r)f(s)]=f_{ab}([r])f_{ab}([s])$

2. that $f_{ab}$ maps $G_{ab}$ to $H_{ab}$:

   Let $[r] \in G_{ab}$ ---> what does this imply? I know that being in [G,G] means being a product of commutators, that is if $g \in [G,G]$, then $g=[g_1,h_1][g_2,h_2],....[g_n,h_n]$ for some finite $n$  but then I am not sure what is the form of the elements in the quotient. Quotienting should be just a regrouping, but still the quotient is something that always comes back to hunt me.

$f_{ab}([r])=[f(r)]$, I have to prove that this is in $H_{ab}$. I know that since f is a group hom
$f([G,G])\subset [H,H]$, but I don't know how to use it here

I know that $G/[G,G]=\{a[G,G]: a \in G\}$, not sure if it helps

3. that $f_{ab}$ does not depend on the representative of the class, i.e if $[r] = [s] \implies f_{ab}([r])=f_{ab}([s])$

$f_{ab}([r])=[f(r)]$... I am not sure how to continue here

4. $F(id_G)=id_{F(G)}$

   Let $[r]\in G_{ab}$

$F(id_G)([r])=(id_G)_{ab}([r])=[id_G(r)]=[r]....?$

5. $F(f\circ g)=F(f)\circ F(g)$

Anything else that I am missing to prove? How do I complete the missing pieces?. At least with points 2 and 3, I would appreciate a detailed explanation, I've been the whole day on this

Many thanks

Comment: Why is 2 even a relevant point here? If you are not certain about 2 then 1 would be nonsense. In the same way that if you are not certain $x\ne 0$ then the expression $1/x$ is nonsense. So either you omit 2 entirely or you put it before 1.

Comment: @Trebor Ok,I had a light suspicion, where exactly in $1)$ Do i need$ 2)$ ? I was just using the definition of $f_{ab}$? I am not sure if omitting would be an option, though it, it's part of the check that the $f_{ab}$ is wel-defined

Comment: How can you prove something is a group homomorphism when you don't even know what the codomain group is? The multiplication symbol might stand for something entirely different, so any algebraic manipulation in 1 without 2 would be invalid.

Comment: In your post you have $ab$ both as a subscript and a superscript. I presume that was a mistake?

Comment: @LeeMosher yeah, typo

Comment: It is more common as a superscript in my experience,btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by (2). If you drop your notation for the cosets, we define $f^{ab}:G^{ab} \rightarrow H^{ab}$ by $f^{ab}(g[G,G]) = f(g)[H,H]$, which is clearly an element of the abelianization of $H$.

I think a more illuminating way to see what's going on is to see where the map $f^{ab}$ comes from. First, you have the factor isomorphism theorem.

> **Theorem:** Let $f:G \rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism and $N \unlhd G$. Then $f$ factors as $f = \psi \pi$ with $\pi:G \rightarrow G/N$ and a well-defined $\psi:G/N \rightarrow H$ if and only if $N \subseteq \ker f$. If this is the case, then $\psi$ is unique and acts by $\psi(gN) = f(g)$.

With this you can prove the universal property of the abelianization.

> **Theorem:**   For any group $G$, its commutator subgroup is normal, and $G/[G,G]$ is abelian. Moreover, if $\varphi:G \rightarrow A$ is any group homomorphism into an abelian group, then $\varphi$ factors through the abelianization of $G$ by $\varphi = \psi \pi$ for $\pi:G \rightarrow G/[G,G]$ and a unique group homomorphism $\psi:G/[G,G] \rightarrow A$.

This says whenever we have a group homomorphism $\varphi$ from $G$ into an abelian group, it will factor through the abelianization of $G$.

Now let $\varphi:G \rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism, i.e a morphism of $\mathbf{Group}$. Denote $\pi:H \rightarrow H/[H,H]$ for the natural projection onto the abelianization. Then we get a composite $\pi \varphi:G \rightarrow H/[H,H]$, and this is still a group homomorphism. However, it is a homomorphism into an abelian group, and so by the universal property of the abelianization, there is a unique group homomorphism $\psi:G/[G,G] \rightarrow H/[H,H]$ for which $\varphi = \psi \pi_G$, where $\pi_G$ is projection onto the abelianization of $G$.

In particular, the functor $F$ from $\mathbf{Group}$ to $\mathbf{Ab}$ groups sending $G$ to $G^{ab}$ and a morphism $f:G \rightarrow H$ to the unique map $\psi:G^{ab} \rightarrow H^{ab}$ which is defined by the universal property of the abelianization. In this way the map $f^{ab}$ is already well-defined from the factor isomorphism theorem, and its definition is more intuitive.

---

**Edit:** As FShrike mentioned, your attempt at well-defined is not quite there. Here is how you might show it manually:

> Suppose $[r] = [s]$. This means that $s^{-1}r \in [G,G]$. In turn, $f(s^{-1}r) \in [H,H]$. Because $f$ is a group homomorphism, $f(s)^{-1}f(r) \in [H,H]$ which implies that $[f(s)] = [f(r)]$, and so $f^{ab}([r]) = f^{ab}([s])$ and the map is well-defined.

In this one uses that if $f$ is a homomorphism $f([a,b]) = [f(a),f(b)]$, which extends to finite products of commutators. You should review the universal property of the abelianization as FShrike mentioned.

Comment: In (2) I was trying to prove that $F(f)=f_{ab}$ has codomain $H_ab$, isn't that part of  proof of the well-definiteness of the functor?.  But looks like you just proved it , are you denoting the cosets by g[G,G]? Was the problem the notation? Can't it be proven using mine?

Comment: Something else all the rest of your answer is to justify (2), right?(so the rest of the points I are still to be proven? Or are they all or some contained in it?) Isn't it  considerable more work  that just doing what you did in the first paragraph?

Comment: I wrote it differently from your notation because writing I thought perhaps $[r]$ and $[f(r)]$ for residue classes was causing the issue for the codomain. With your notation $f_{ab}([r]) = [f(r)]$ is certainly a map into the abelianization of $H$. I wrote the rest to give you background for where the definition of $f_{ab}$ comes from. Yes you could certainly do it directly by simply checking its well-defined. This just shows that it is already well-defined if you know where the map is coming from.

Comment: Does the following argument work ?  Let's see "by hand" that  $f_{ab}$ does not depend on the representative of the class, i.e if $[r] = [s] \implies f_{ab}([r])=f_{ab}([s])$. 
Since $r$ and $s$ are in the same class $[r]=[s]$ and $f$ is a group homo, then elements in the same coset map to the same element(Not sure about this and I can't find a proof of it!, because $f $ has domain $G$ ), $f(r)=f(s) \implies$

$f_{ab}([r])=[f(r)]=[f(s)]=f_{ab}([s])$

Comment: Edited @some_math_guy

Comment: How did you arrive at $s^{-1}r \in [G,G]$ ?

Comment: This is a basic property of cosets. $aH = bH \iff b^{-1}a \in H$.

Comment: The wikipedia page on commnutator:  says that it holds that for a homomorphism $f: G \rightarrow H: f[G,G] \subset [H,H]$, you seem to be using  $f[G,G] = [H,H]$ as stated in your last paragraph?

Comment: There is no such assertion in the last paragraph.

Comment: You are right, where did this come from  "$f$ is a homomorphism $f([a,b]) = [f(a),f(b)]$,"? What is [a,b]?  The clases in the problem act on a single argument like [a]

Comment: Please read about commutator subgroups and the abelianization. $[a,b] = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is a commutator. This is also why you might want to use coset notation $r[G,G]$ rather than $[r]$ so as to not have to mentally keep track of which quotient group you are in.

Comment: Sorry, yes, for A moment I was thinking it was like a class for an order pair $(a,b)$. Yeah I read the wikipedia pages. That's why I though you where using $[a,b] \in [G,G] $and $[f(a), f(b)] \in [H,H]$, that $f([G,G])=[H,H]$ for the particular elements.. But I guess it was only a matter of writting the commutator definition: $f([a,b])=f(aba^{-1}b^{-1})=f(a)f(b)f(a)^{-1}f(b)^{-1}=[f(a),f(b)]$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\grp}{\mathsf{Grp}}\newcommand{\ab}{\mathsf{Ab}}$In a sense, you don't need to know anything about groups here. I'll give a general perspective. However, you should definitely invest energy into understanding more concretely why $F$ is a functor.

There is an inclusion/forgetful functor $\iota:\ab\to\grp$ and you have a family of objects $(F(G))_{G\in\grp}\subseteq\ab$ with the following property:

> $(\ast)$ There are isomorphisms $\ab(F(G),H)\cong\grp(G,\iota(H))$ which are natural in $H$

You hopefully know that these isomorphisms actually exist (in order to have Abelianisation!); the best choice of isomorphism is by taking a homomorphism $f:F(G)\to H$ and the unit $\eta:G\to F(G)$ and send $f$ to the composite $f\eta:G\to H=\iota(H)$ in $\grp$. To see that's natural in $H$ is very easy; say $h:H\to H'$ is a homomorphism, then $(hf)$ is sent to $(hf)\eta=h(f\eta)$ as needed.

The statement $(\ast)$ is immediately sufficient to **uniquely** extend $F$ to a functor such that those isomorphisms are natural in $G$ too. Explicitly for $f:G\to G'$ the homomorphism $G\overset{f}{\to}G'\overset{\eta}{\to}F(G')=\iota(F(G'))$ induces, via $(\ast)$, a homomorphism $F(f):F(G)\to F(G')$.

Why do I say you don't need to know anything about groups? Because this is a completely general situation.

> Suppose $\mathsf{C},\mathsf{D}$ are categories, $R:\mathsf{D}\to\mathsf{C}$ a functor such that there exists a family of objects $L(c)$, for $c\in\mathsf{C}$, and isomorphisms $\mathsf{D}(L(c),d)\cong\mathsf{C}(c,R(d))$ which are natural in $d$. Then $L$ uniquely lifts to a functor making these isomorphisms natural in $c$ and we get an adjunction $L\dashv R$.

There is another way to state this in terms of initial/terminal morphisms, but I'll stop there.

Comment: I am not familiar with (*) and I don't know what you mean by natural. Is that a precise definition? I haven't seen adjunction either yet. I am just in the second week of the course, so I am supossed to use only what I have so far. Isn't it possible and correct to do it my way?

Comment: @some_math_guy ‘Natural’ is a precise and very important term. If you’re just learning about functors then very soon you’ll encounter the concept of a natural transformation between functors. I assumed that if you were talking about Abelianisation in a category-theoretic way then you’d be familiar with adjunctions but if not then I guess this won’t make much sense to you yet. But you can ignore the abstract stuff and just work with the definition, $F(f):F(G)\to F(G’)$ is the unique map induced by $G\to G’\to F(G’)$.

Comment: Could you tell me if the following argument works?:  Let's see "by hand" that  $f_{ab}$ does not depend on the representative of the class, i.e if $[r] = [s] \implies f_{ab}([r])=f_{ab}([s])$. 
Since $r$ and $s$ are in the same class $[r]=[s]$ and $f$ is a group homo, then elements in the same coset map to the same element, $f(r)=f(s) \implies$

$f_{ab}([r])=[f(r)]=[f(s)]=f_{ab}([s])$

Comment: @some_math_guy It's suspicious because I'm not sure if you actually know why elements in the same coset map to elements in the same coset. It's not true for completely general group quotients and completely general group homomorphisms. And $f(r)=f(s)$ isn't necessarily true.

Comment: but is it true in this case? Otherwise my verification does not work. I think it is true because the commutator is a normal subgroup, not that I have seen a proof or anything though, I just can't find one but I am taking it as a fact, if you corroborate it.

Comment: @some_math_guy It's true but your proof isn't really a proof. The commutator being a normal subgroup is relevant in that it allows us to define a quotient *group* but it's not really relevant for this point

Comment: I recommend you revise why abelianisation has the universal property

Comment: what proof isn't really a proof ? The one above that $f_{ab}$ does not depend on the representative of the class?

Comment: @some_math_guy Yeah, that one. If you understand why we have: "for all Abelian groups $H$ and homomorphisms $f:G\to H$ there is a unique homomorphism $F(G)\to H$ such that $G\to F(G)\to H$ equals $f$" (**and this is the whole reason we care about $F$ as a functor**) then you can understand why $f_{ab}$ is well-defined

Comment: Well, it's a consecuence of the isomorphism theorem, as described above in the answer of Irving Ravin, and that gives me the well-definitiness automatically I am aware of that. I am just trying to do the check by hand withouth using any of that. So I don't really understand why is my proof not valid. Can it be fixed somehow?(again just "by hand").

Comment: The only step I was unsure about was the fact that  elements in the same coset map to elements in the same coset, but with that every step is justified, I think. Of course to prove it is well defined by hand, I also proved that $f_{ab}$ is a group hom.

Comment: @some_math_guy Your proof isn't exactly wrong. It's common for new students to write proofs that are basically stating "it's right because it's right" and that's not.. wrong, but I don't have faith in your understanding when you write a proof like that. So you should focus on that "elements in the same coset map to elements in the same coset" and try to explicitly prove this for yourself e.g. ... say $[r]=[s]$. Then [do some stuff] therefore $[f(r)]=[f(s)]$ (or do it some other way)